# Android Image Recognition API/library (not in the cloud)

Tags: android, image-processing, image-recognition

I have searched for a good Android Image Recognition API/library. I found some but they don't suit me because we have to put images on their server. I want one that allows you to search on your own server.

I have a list of products (name + image) in my database. I want to allow the user to snap a picture with his mobile and get related products images.

**EDIT**

After searching, I haven't found a library that can completely suit my need (searching on your own server). But I found one that is perfect compared to others (attach metadata to images with json, upload multiple images for an item): **Kooaba**. Unfortunately, there is not an Android library for Kooaba. Would be awesome if you can recommend something like Kooaba for Android.

Answer (score 6):

Opencv is  a computer vision set of libraries written in C++ by intel.It has a version for android i have used it but u need to have android phone as latest as possible.because with the version 2.2 and 2.3 you will only be able to run CV Camera App.So i would say a device with API level 11 or higher is better.
It is best suited if you use it in linux

1. setup linux(Ubuntu)
2. Download the Android SDK for Linux
3. Download the Android NDK for linux
4. Download the [OpenCV for Android](http://opencv.org/platforms/android/)
5. Here are tutorials [For-API8](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/Tutorial-2-OpenCV-for-Android-Setup-Linux-API8.pdf) and [For-API11](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/Tutorial-2-OpenCV-for-Android-Setup-Linux-API11.pdf) for Stanford University to get you started with opencv and android
6. Another page from stanford to get some help

Hope that it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenCV sdk for image detection. If you just wanted to recognise face then use androids own class refer this link http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/face-detection-with-android-apis.html

Answer (score 1):

What about moodstocks.com ? It's a nice library and works like a charm

Comment: In the title says "not in the cloud". MoodStocks it's NOT a library, it is an "on cloud API"